# How To Test In PayPal Sandbox For Failed, Skipped Payments For Recurring/Automatic Payment Profiles?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions, recurring-billing

I'm trying to find a way how to test in PayPal sandbox when a customer fails to make a recurring payment. For example, running a membership site, there is always a lot of failed or skipped payments for recurring payments (not the first payment - future payments, for example, they pay the first month for a 1 monthly subscription, but the next month the payment fails or skips).

We have set up in our site to cancel the subscription instantly overiding the default PayPal's "We will try in 5 days" to take the money again. But our issue is how can we test this in PayPal sandbox?

Currently, we have no issues testing recurring payments in sandbox, but we are needing it to fail, so for example, when a member hasn't got any funds to continue their membership subscription. Any help would be great.

Comment: Were you able to figure out a way to test this?